During salat I was rising from prostration, I said Allah hu akbar but while saying bar my lips didn't touch each other but it almost sounded like bar
During salat I was rising from prostration, I said Allah hu akbar but while saying bar my lips didn't touch each other but it almost sounded like bar. So do I need to repeat my prayer and it occurs to me frequently
